# Laravel Api only returns empty objects

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to return an object from my Laravel api routes, but all that's returned is an empty array.

My model looks like this:

```
    class MobilePageStats extends Model
    {
        //
        private $score;
        private $mobileFriendly;
        private $numberRobotedResources;
        private $numberTransientFetchFailureResources;
        private $transientFetchFailureUrls;
        private $cms;
        private $ruleResults;

        /**
         * MobilePageStats constructor.
         * @param int $score
         * @param bool $mobileFriendly
         * @param int $numberRobotedResources
         * @param int $numberTransientFetchFailureResources
         * @param array $transientFetchFailureUrls
         * @param string $cms
         * @param array $ruleResults
         */
        public function __construct(
            $score,
            $mobileFriendly,
            $numberRobotedResources,
            $numberTransientFetchFailureResources,
            $transientFetchFailureUrls,
            $cms,
            $ruleResults
        ) {
            $this->score = $score;
            $this->mobileFriendly = $mobileFriendly;
            $this->numberRobotedResources = $numberRobotedResources;
            $this->numberTransientFetchFailureResources = $numberTransientFetchFailureResources;
            $this->transientFetchFailureUrls = $transientFetchFailureUrls;
            $this->cms = $cms;
            $this->ruleResults = $ruleResults;
        }
```

And I also got getters on everything.

I set all the data in my controller with the constructor, in this function:

```
public function getData() {
            $cms = "";
            $score = $this->data->ruleGroups->USABILITY->score;
            $mobileFriendly = $this->data->ruleGroups->USABILITY->pass;
            if(isset($this->data->pageStats->numberRobotedResources)){
                $numberRobotedResources = $this->data->pageStats->numberRobotedResources;
            }else{
                $numberRobotedResources = '';
            }
            if(isset($this->data->pageStats->numberTransientFetchFailureResources)){
                $numberTransientFetchFailureResources = $this->data->pageStats->numberTransientFetchFailureResources;
            }else{
                $numberTransientFetchFailureResources = '';
            }
            if(isset($this->data->pageStats->transientFetchFailureUrls)){
                $transientFetchFailureUrls =  $this->data->pageStats->transientFetchFailureUrls;
            }else{
                $transientFetchFailureUrls = '';
            }
            if(isset($this->data->pageStats->cms)){
                $cms = $this->data->pageStats->cms;
                if($cms != 'WORDPRESS' && $cms != 'JOOMLA'){
                    $cms = $this->checkCMS();
                }
            }
            $cvp = $this->getConfigureViewport();
            $fontSizes = $this->getUseLegibleFontSizes();
            $avoidPlugins = $this->getAvoidPlugins();
            $sizeToViewport = $this->getSizeContentToViewport();
            $tapTargets = $this->getSizeTapTargetsAppropriately();
            $ruleResults = [$cvp, $fontSizes, $avoidPlugins, $sizeToViewport, $tapTargets];


            $mobilePageStats = new MobilePageStats($score, $mobileFriendly, $numberRobotedResources,
                $numberTransientFetchFailureResources, $transientFetchFailureUrls, $cms, $ruleResults);

            return $mobilePageStats;

        }
```

In my API routes I then try to return the model like this:

```
Route::get('/mobilePageSpeed', function(Request $request){
    $data = new PageSpeedMobileController($request->url);
    return response($data->getData());
});
```

But all I get returned when I make the request is:

```
<body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[]</pre>
</body>
```

Why is the object not returned? I know it contains data, because I can print it. But can't send it?

I have tried both repsonse()->json($data->getData()); And json_encode($data->getData()), but they give me the same result? I just can't seem to find a solution that works.

So how do I return objects from Laravel Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be to json_encode every single object after you cast them to arrays. Should work :)

Comment: Nice, that did the trick!! But I still had to return it as an json response

Answer (score 0):

You override the original Model constructor with your version, the model is not filled with attributes nor booted.

I dunno what you want to achieve but if you extends a class from Eloquent\Model you cannot override is own costructor without calling the original one, i.e.:

```
 public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
 {
    parent::__construct($attributes);
```

Comment: I tryed to remove the extends Model, cause I really don't need the extension of Model, as far as I know. But this gave the same result. So I don't think that this will solve my issue.

Comment: I dont want to be rude but If its the same for you to extends from Model or not I cant follow you: I have no time for a game of try and retry. I pointed an important issue of your code, do your homework and your tries and if you have still problems post another question.

Comment: I get your point, and I tried to add parent construct, but this did not solve my issue.
The reason that I don't think is necessary for me to extend model, is because it's only generated object, that I don't save it in an database or anything, its purpose is only to hold my data.

I am thankful for that you used your time to look into my issue, but I did do my homework, tried almost every solution that I could find, but it's  still not working.

Comment: I can add only an advice: look in the Eloquent Model source for the __toString() and toJson() functions. If you return a response() you have to give to that function a string or a array.